# PHPExcel INDEX using AGGREGATE function yields to corrupted file

Tags: formula, phpexcel

I want to extract "topten" values, correctly handling tie cases.
I need to use the following formula:
    =INDEX($A$4:$A$12,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($K$4:$K$12)-ROW($K$4)+1)/($K$4:$K$12=O4),COUNTIF($O$4:O4,O4)))

If I use this formula in my code I have a corrupted file that I can read with a text editor and that shows:
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: Consolidation Transporteur!N4 -> Formula Error: Wrong number of arguments for INDEX() function: 5 given, between 1 and 4 expected in /home/.../PHPExcel/Cell.php:293
Stack trace:

- 0 /home/.../PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(754): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
- 1 /home/.../PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php(373): PHPExcel_Worksheet->calculateColumnWidths()
- 2 /home/.../PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php(80): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->_writeCols(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
  Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet))
- 3 /home/.../PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php(304): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->writeWorksheet(Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet),
  Array, true)
- 4 /home/....output.php(33): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('/tmp/phpxltmpqF...')
- 5  in **/home/.../PHPExcel/Cell.php** on line **293**

If I write the formula without the leading equal sign, I can open the Excel file, insert the equal sign and the formula gives the correct result, showing that the formula is correct with a correct number of arguments

If I use a simple MATCH function instead of the AGGREGATE one, I can get the "topten" values but tie cases are not correctly handled.

I also need to keep the setPreCalculateFormulas to true.

How can I solve this formula issue?